# Spring Boot: How to securely authenticate two different kinds of user using NextJs as a frontend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, next.js, spring-security

I have never really done authentication yet. At this moment, I'm stuck and not really sure on what would be the best and most secure way to handle it.
To get an overview on what I'm working with:

For the backend/REST API I'm using Spring Boot and for the frontend NextJs.

Furthermore, Two types of users are needed, some who can either create, analyze or manage content (basically different roles) in our custom CMS. And on the other side, app users who are consuming this content (on a iOS app).
That's what I'm trying to achieve as a minimum requirement, but it would be even better if it would somehow be possible to manage only a list of specific content for a specific role (e.g. analyze). Like for example, only blog articles that are in this list.
I know it's a really broad question, but I would be happy with some general directions or links to resources that could guide me in a way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JWT logic.

Try to look to this video: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVdQ3iuovg0**

In Backend (Springboot application) you must prepare user entity with a custom roles. Then you need to create JWT implementation for making JWTs from User instance. All this things are described in the video.

It works like this:

- Your frontend - NextJS - sends authentication request to backend with the user credentials.
- Your backend tries to authenticate this user - check if a user exists in the database (with a specific role) , then JWT token is created and sends back to frotend. JWT contains informations about user, it means role, name, etc...
- Your frontend obtain a JWT, save it into a session, using Next-Auth for example.
- When you need to show specific content for the user with a specific role, FE sends request to the BE with JWT. If this user have authorization rights for this content, BE checks JWT and sends data back.

Comment: It would be better if you added some code to this answer and specify where exactly the checks happen

Comment: It's in the video, but for explanation, this JWT check works on Spring filter chain. Custom JWT filter is added into filter chain and it check validity with every request.